# How to handle session change notifications in Qt tray application?

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, qt5

I have a problem with handling session state notifications (like user logon/logoff/lock etc) in Qt tray application. In usual Qt application I can call `WTSRegisterSessionNotification` with `hWnd=effectiveWinId()` and re-implement `nativeEvent` like this:

```
bool EventListener::nativeEvent(const QByteArray &eventType, void *message, long *result)
{    
    MSG* msg = reinterpret_cast<MSG*>(message);
    switch(msg->message)
    {
        case WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE:
            ...
    }

    ...
}
```

But in tray application it's impossible, because `QSystemTrayIcon` doesn't inherits from `QWidget` and I haven't any window handle.

Is it possible to resolve the problem without creating fake invisible window?

Comment: There is a window handle behind the `QSystemTrayIcon` instance, but I don't think you can readily get hold of it. Create a message only window and pass that to `WTSRegisterSessionNotification`. That's a better solution anyway.

Comment: was the problem solved? I need to implement the same. I'm using the similar steps, and window which represent the settings of tray app (inherited from QDialog, and not destroyed , just hidden most of time) but don't receive such messages into nativeEvent

Comment: @amigo421 Yes, I posted a small example as answer right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a fake invisible window with WinAPI functions for notification handling. Here is a short example how to make it:

```
QObject *ni = reinterpret_cast<QObject*>(QGuiApplication::platformNativeInterface() );

// Register window class in the platform plugin.
QString className;
void *wndProc = reinterpret_cast<void *>(msgWndProc);
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(ni, "registerWindowClass", Qt::DirectConnection,
                               Q_RETURN_ARG(QString, className),
                               Q_ARG(QString, QStringLiteral("MessageFakeWindowClass")),
                               Q_ARG(void *, wndProc));

const wchar_t windowName[] = L"MessageFakeWindow";
HWND msgWindow_ = CreateWindowEx(0, (wchar_t*)className.utf16(),
                      windowName, WS_OVERLAPPED,
                      0, 0,
                      0, 0,
                      HWND_DESKTOP, nullptr, (HINSTANCE)GetModuleHandle(0), nullptr);

WTSRegisterSessionNotification(msgWindow_, NOTIFY_FOR_THIS_SESSION);
```

Comment: thank you. also got my code working , my mistake was a using effectiveWid() instead of wId()